# Convert const char* to Platfrom::Array<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

I want to convert `const char*` from `(std:string)str.data()` to generic Windows C++ `Array<unsigned char>` for `DataWriter::WriteBytes()`method.

Comment: `Array<unsigned char> arr(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(str.c_str()), static_cast<unsigned int>(str.size()));`

Comment: Generally, if you ever feel the need to use C-style casting (as is done here) you should almost always take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.